# Simple gallery app ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gallery

I've got an NSMutableArray with images, I would like to have a simple scrolling gallery with them. Each image is 1024x768 and it should fit when in Portrait and be full screen when in Landscape with autorotation. I'm using ATPageView gallery but I cannot handle all this stuff. Are there any ideas?
Here is what I use now:

```
- (UIView *)viewForPageInPagingView:(ATPagingView *)pagingView atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"In view for PV index %i", index);

   // if (view == nil) 
    //{
    float coef;
    if (self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        coef=1.34f;
    }
    else
    {
        coef=1;
    }

    UIView *view = [pagingView dequeueReusablePage];
    NSLog(@" Paging viewer View Size: %.2f %.2f", pagingViewer.frame.size.width, pagingViewer.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@" Paging viewer SUBVIEWS View Size: %@", [pagingViewer.subviews objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@" Nutral View Size: %.2f %.2f",neutralView.frame.size.width, neutralView.frame.size.height);
    //view.frame=CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width/coef, view.frame.size.height/coef);
        UIImage *presentImg=[largeImagesFromGallery objectAtIndex:index];


        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, presentImg.size.width/coef, presentImg.size.height/coef)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
     NSLog(@" Size of the view: %.2f %.2f",view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);



        UIScrollView *sv=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, presentImg.size.width/coef, presentImg.size.height/coef)];
        sv.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, presentImg.size.width/coef, presentImg.size.height/coef)];
        img.image=[largeImagesFromGallery objectAtIndex:index];
        img.tag=2000;
        sv.contentSize=presentImg.size;
        sv.maximumZoomScale=3.0f;

        sv.delegate=self;
        [sv addSubview:img];

        view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [view addSubview:sv];

    //}
        return view;
}
```

Comment: What's your issue/error?  Are you looking for a re-usable gallery or are you having a specific issue with this code?

Comment: I think I would like to have a good reusable gallary just like the one I'm already using

Answer (score 1):

this link may help you.

Here you need to just some customization for landscape and portrait to, just remove pagecontroll or hide it and make image size of your need.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/